# What is the correct MySQL database statement where the variable defined as all the rows

Tags: php, mysql

I try to explain this well folks,

I have a database with 20 questions with two principles : 1) Cardiology and 2) Endocrine. And you can select using HTML selection menu either of the concepts or you can select 3) All.

And on my html page I have a selection menu with 3 options and they each have a value:

```
<div id="selectContainer1">
<select id="selectedPrinciple" name="selectedPrinciple">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a System</option>

        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="VASCULAR">Cardiology, Vascular System</option>
        <option value="ENDOCRINE">Endocrine</option>

    </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Start">
```

I have this code on php:

```
$selectedPrinciple = $_POST['selectedPrinciple']; 

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM qbanktable WHERE Principle = '$selectedPrinciple'"
```

Now when I select option "Cardiology" or "Endocrine", all the rows that are related to those are picked from my database and showed on the next page. But when I select "All" I get a syntax error because of course as it does have no value the row cannot be found on my database. Is there anything I can put for the option value for "All" that the mysql returns all the rows?

Comment: There's several issues at play here.  The most important is that your query is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).  Next is that your code will throw a notice / warning if `$_POST['selectedPrinciple']` is not set.  Third, while you've sliced off a nice minimal amount of code, you haven't provided enough context to know how to give you the best method for tackling this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if `$selectedPrinciple` is `empty()` and modify the query accordingly.

```
$selectedPrinciple = $_POST['selectedPrinciple']; 
if(!empty($selectedPrinciple)) {
// this line indicates that you don't use prepared statements
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `qbanktable` WHERE `Principle` = '$selectedPrinciple'";
} else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `qbanktable`";
}
```

full example using mysqli prepared statement

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";    
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);    
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$selectedPrinciple = $_POST['selectedPrinciple']; 
if(!empty($selectedPrinciple)) {
// prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `qbanktable` WHERE `Principle` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $selectedPrinciple);
} else {
// prepare
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `qbanktable`");
}    
// execute
$stmt->execute();
// fetch data
if (!($res = $stmt->get_result())) {
   echo "Failed to fetch the result set: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
// print data
print_r($res->fetch_all());
// close prepared statement
$stmt->close();
// close connection
$conn->close();
```

Comment: You should at least mention the fact that using string interpolation in SQL is dangerous and opens the DB up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: SQL injection is true, but it is for a group of 10 people so hopefully non is that skilled

Comment: If it's on the internet, you have to think about *bad visitors*, NOT about your intended audience.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to use a few techniques to "build" my query, like so:

**NOTE:**
I'm demonstrating how to do this with PDO and parameter binding, because **your query is open to SQL injection attacks**.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `qbanktable`";

$where = [];
$params = [];

if ( ! empty( $_POST['selectedPrinciple'] ) ) {
    $where[] = '`Principle` = ?';
    $params[] = $_POST['selectedPrinciple'];
}

if ( /* some other condition */ ) {
    // add to the $where / $params as appropriate
}

// Glue the $where into a string
$where = implode( ' AND ', $where );

// Append where to the $sql statement
$sql .= ( $where ) ? ' WHERE ' . $where : '';

// assumes $conn is already a set-up PDO connection
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute( $params );
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to check in PHP if the value of selectedPrinciple is something like ALL or is empty, and then don´t add the WHERE part of the query.

If really want to use some value for All option, you can try to use one or two percents signs '%' or '%%', but I don´t remember if it works. However, I don´t recommend this approach. Take care also about SQL Injection.